# Laravel Livewire Dispatch To Render From Child To Parent Cause Error in Data

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire

I have been figuring this one for a day without any solution. Saw several videos but this error is really strange.

I just want to call refresh to parent whenever the item has been deleted.

Here is the parent that I wish to update ListingManage.php (controller) [PARENT]

```
class ListingManage extends Component
{
    use WithPagination;
    protected $listings;
    public $meta;

    public function mount(){
        $this->meta = PageMetaController::create('admin.listing.manage');
    }
    #[Computed()]
    public function render()
    {
        // Show toast whenever successfully ordered something
        if(session('show-toast')){
            $this->dispatch('show-toast',session('show-toast'));
        }
        $this->listings = ListingData::with(['listing_detail'])->where('status','active')->latest()->paginate(10);

        return view('livewire.admin.listing.listing-manage',['listings'=>$this->listings])->extends('layouts.app',['meta' => $this->meta]);
    }

    #[On('refresh')]
    public function refresh(){
        $this->listings = ListingData::with(['listing_detail'])->where('status','active')->latest()->paginate(10);
    }
}
```

listing-manage.blade file [PARENT]

```
<div class="py-3">
    <div class="max-w-7xl mx-auto sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
        <div class="bg-white overflow-hidden shadow-sm sm:rounded-lg">
            <div class="p-3 lg:p-6">
                <x-primary-button wire:click="refresh">Refresh</x-primary-button>
                <h2 class="text-center font-bold capitalize mb-3">{{ __('Manage Listing') }}</h2>
                <x-shared.loading wire:loading />
                @if (count($listings) > 0)
                    @foreach ($listings as $listing)
                        @if ($listing)
                            <livewire:shared.listing-item :listing="$listing" :key="$listing->id"></livewire:shared.listing-item>
                        @endif
                    @endforeach
                    {{ $listings->links(data: ['scrollTo' => false]) }}
                @else
                    <x-shared.widget-not-found>{{ __(':show not found', ['show' => 'listing']) }}</x-shared.widget-not-found>
                @endif
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now here is the child where the list is stored there.

ListingItem.php (controller) [CHILD]

```
<?php

namespace App\Livewire\Shared;

use App\Http\Controllers\ListingDataController;
use App\Models\ListingData;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Livewire\Attributes\Modelable;
use Livewire\Attributes\Reactive;
use Livewire\Component;

class ListingItem extends Component
{
    public $redirectTo = 'admin';
    public ListingData $listing;
    #[Modelable]
    public $editUrl;

    public function mount(){
        switch ($this->redirectTo) {
            case 'admin':
                $this->editUrl = route('admin.listing.edit',['listing' => $this->listing->id]);
                break;

            case 'dashboard':
                $this->editUrl = route('dashboard.listing.edit',['listing' => $this->listing->id]);
                break;
        }
    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.shared.listing-item');
    }

    public function delete(ListingData $listing){
        $res = ListingDataController::destroy(listingData:$listing);

        if($res->status()!=200){
            $this->dispatch('show-toast',['status' => 'error', 'message' => $res->getData()->message]);
            return;
        }
        $this->dispatch('refresh');
        $this->dispatch('show-toast',['status'=>'success', 'message' => $res->getData()->message]);
    }

    public function edit(){
        $this->dispatch('edit-listing',$this->listing->id);
    }
}
```

listing-item.blade [PARENT]

```
<div class="border rounded-xl mb-3 overflow-hidden grid grid-cols-12">
    <div class="col-span-12 md:col-span-5 lg:col-span-4 flex justify-center relative">
        <img class="h-[200px] object-cover w-full" src="{{ $listing->listing_detail->images[0] ?? '' }}" />
        <x-tools.category-text :listing="$listing" class="p-2 text-xs absolute bottom-0 mb-2 right-0 capitalize bg-gray-800 bg-opacity-80 rounded-l-lg text-white"/>
    </div>
    <div class="col-span-12 md:col-span-7 lg:col-span-8 p-2">
        <div class="text-center text-gray-900 whitespace-nowrap overflow-hidden mb-2">{{ $listing->title }}</div>
        <div class="text-center mb-2"><x-widget.card-specification :listing="$listing"/></div>
        <div class="flex flex-wrap gap-2 justify-end mb-2">
            <x-shared.primary-link href="{{ $editUrl }}">Edit</x-shared.primary-link>
                <x-danger-button wire:click="delete({{$listing}})" wire:confirm="{{__('Do you want to delete (:listing)',['listing'=>$listing->title])}}">Delete</x-danger-button>
        </div>
        <x-tools.location-text :listing="$listing" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Error Condition

- When I click the delete button, it triggers "refresh" dispatch
- Then we delete the data and we need to refresh the parent
- The parent is refreshed but the data went error. I cannot even click the other delete buttons.
- On the other hand when I delete #1 item. Then #1, and 3-10 would be banished.
- However, when I delete the last item #10. It works.